# NetBeans 7.3 - disable closing brackets and parentheses automatically

Tags: javascript, ide, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans 7.3 to edit JavaScript files.

Whenever I type a `(` or a `[`, NetBeans automatically inserts a `)` or a `]`.

I find this annoying (it also doesn't always work correctly).

Is there a way to turn this feature off?

This was possible in NetBeans 7.2 by disabling the following feature:

- *Insert Closing Brackets Automatically*

However, it no longer works in NetBeans 7.3

In NetBeans 7.3 this feature only controls whether or not closing brackets are added after if statements, for loops, etc...

Comment: [This issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229147) has been opened as a request to implement this feature...

Answer (score 1):

In version 7.2 this feature can be disabled via `Options > Editor > Code Completion > "Insert Closing Brackets Automatically"`.
Should be the same for 7.3

Comment: The same feature is there, but in NetBeans 7.3 it does **NOT** disable this behavior.  That's why I'm so confused... It used to work, but now it doesn't.  In NetBeans 7.3 that checkbox only controls whether or not a `}` is automatically inserted when you type **if statements**.  There appears to be no way to turn it off for normal parens and brackets.

Comment: Next time please add insights like this to the question, if you already found it out. Just updated to 7.3, too, and I think you just found a bug. It doesn't work for me either, but in v7.2 it also works on parentheses. Create a bugreport in this case.